# Converting SVN project to maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have downloaded a project (Maven based structure) from our SVN repository using Eclipse SVN plugin. Initially, Eclipse wasn't recognizing it as java project so I had to follow the following steps:
http://www.javaexperience.com/how-to-convert-svn-project-to-regular-eclipse-java-project/

The above steps worked well and the project was converted to java project.

Next I right clicked on the project and selected maven->Convert to maven project. Eclipse downloaded some jars and added it to the class path but not all files seem to have been downloaded successfully as I see Junit jar file missing error (where as junit is mentioned in pom.xml)

When I right click on the pom.xml file, I don't see the option "mvn install" or "mvn clean". I am using Eclipse Kepler which comes with maven plugin out of the box.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find the Maven commands in 'Run As', not in 'Maven'

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a maven project using create maven project menu then add the SVN based source code to it.